# To work with a team of reliable software development freelancers, which platforms can I use and how do I get started?

Tags: group-freelancing

Normally, freelance platforms like UpWork, Guru, Fiverr etc. allow freelancers to offer solo services. Are there platforms that allow freelancers to join a group of software developers to deliver projects?

How do I join such projects, and how do I know if they are reliable/reputed? Any pros and cons I should be aware of?

**The benefits to the client:**

- It can improve turnaround time.
- A global community of freelancers contributes their experience.

Comment: What sector? What types of product? What are your requirements? We're missing sufficient information here, I'm afraid.

Comment: @CamilStaps did it

Comment: why the close vote? can someone explain?

Comment: Hi Ali, as Camil mentioned, you should add more details to this, as the answers may very well depend on what it is that you're doing. Also, could you expand more on the "freelancers group". What do you mean by this? An online forum? A professional organization? Something else?  Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe people are close-voting as NARQ because "good idea" sounds too vague. I would suggest re-formulating your question like this: "My domain is X. I have tried Y, but apparently it made problem of Z. What are key points in order to make my Y activity bring me money/reputation/contacts in a timely manner?" Otherwise, the answers "yes, team up" and "no, work alone" would be equally valid.

Comment: Good question, but needs a little more to it, right now an answer of 'yes' should be enough. -- I think the question could be "what are the benefits of ....?"

Comment: How about "How should I decide whether to...?"

Answer (score 5):

I have always worked this way (with the exception of technical writing gigs).  In general teaming up with other freelancers makes it possible to deliver greater guarantees than you can by yourself, and it makes it possible to tackle larger projects as well.  There are some difficulties in working with new people (making work styles gel, ensuring you send eachother work that is appropriate to your expertise, etc) but these can be managed.

Now there are many times when this is not appropriate.  I cannot imagine technical writing being a good case for this sort of team work because often clients want specific writers, but for more functional tools, it is generally a good thing.

There are two other points I would make in terms of IT services and software:

1. I have found that many customers have had bad experiences with loners, and that loners are harder to replace than team players.  This makes being a loner a possible red flag for a customer.  If you want to work alone you should be aware of this and at least have partnerships where you can hand off projects.
2. One of the very good things about teaming up is that if one team member takes on something that turns out to be outside his or her expertise, it may be possible to salvage the situation by handing it off to someone else.  This is far harder to do working alone.

Comment: Hi Chris. Could you share more info on which platforms such gigs are available, and how we could verify if the client is reputable? Any pros and cons and precautions would also help.